How to tell if wires overheated in the between receptacles
I was wondering if it was possible to identify if a cable/wire was damaged by overheating on a circuit of receptacles without opening the drywall to verify.
For context, my spouse replaced some receptacles in our house.  In some cases, the receptacle was a half switch and one of the two plugs connected to a light switch (though still on one breaker), and the connecting tab between the two hot wires wasn't removed.
These receptacles were used for a day or two until I corrected the problem.  Now I was wondering if any damage was done to the wires during that time, if the damage was severe, and how I could identify it.  The wires connecting the receptacles look perfectly fine but I was wondering if there was a way to identify cables that were damaged by overheating without opening the drywall.  Perhaps with a multimeter or some other tool.
Thank you.

Is there something specific prompting this concern, e.g. smelling smoke in the house, or burn damage on the old receptacles you replaced, or a concern about something you saw or did while replacing the outlets?

@Mark Hi Mark, the problem is the my spouse decided to change the outlets on her own without knowing what she was doing. In some cases there were half receptacles that were connected to switches and she didn't remove the tab for the hot wires.  The way these were wired was that they were on a single breaker (two receptacles were on 1 breaker and 1 was on a separate breaker) and neither breaker went off.  I have since corrected the problem but I'm worried that some stuff is going on behind the walls.  I don't smell any smoke, the wires in the boxes look perfect.

All that not breaking the tab on a half-switched outlet does is make the switch useless. It won't cause an overload. When the tab isn't removed on an MWBC, it makes a dead short which usually causes the breaker to trip very fast and also not overheat the wires ;^) What you might want to do (and educate your spouse about, it they are prone to tackling electrical repairs) is to check the torque on all the receptacle screws, which is (now) required by code, and prevents problems that typically lead to overheating at the outlet when a loose connection starts arcing, sometimes years later.

@Ecnerwal, I don't think she will be touching wiring again.  I find it very interesting but I hate doing electrical work myself because I know nothing about it and the stakes seem very high if I get it wrong.  I was actually wondering if it would be possible to take an electricians course part time and become a certified electrician as a second job.  There was an issue with 3 MWBCs in our kitchen, the breaker kept tripping and I think it caused one of the breakers to fail and now electricity is always flowing to one of the wires.  We capped them all individually until an electrician can look.

While taking courses can be informative, for an electrician license (there are a few types), most locales require several thousand hours or a few years of work experience, so it isn't really a part-time kind of thing.

Overheating does not happen all by itself. It would have to be the result of someone connecting a very large load without the proper overcurrent protection device (breaker) being used. Have you ever done this?
And if that ever happened, the damage would almost invariably be at the connections/junctions, i.e. at connected receptacles and splices inside boxes, not in the wire runs in the middle of a wall.
And simple overheating would rarely require wire replacement. It would take a LOT of overheating to cause enough damage to the insulation to make for an ongoing hazard.
Take these words to heart: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it!"

@kreemowheet, Thank you for the response, I worry because, I didn't originally do the work, my spouse did without my knowledge and when things stopped working, she asked me to fix it. I know nothing about electricity but I learned quite a bit and fixed
everything.  However, in some cases, there were half receptacles connected to switches and she didn't remove the connecting tab between the hot wires.  She used the receptacles for a couple of days and nothing went wrong and the breakers didn't trip.  Again, I fixed the problem but I wanted to make sure there was no damage to the wires.

@JayFou - You can rest assured.  When a half-switched receptacle that is all on one circuit is replaced but the tab isn't removed, the only problem is the switch stops working - you can't turn off the switched half.  It doesn't cause any kind of overcurrent situation.  If a receptacle is on a multiwire branch circuit (MWBC) and the tab isn't removed, the circuit breaker will trip immediately, preventing any damage.

@Mark, Thank you so much Mark for taking the time to answer my question.  It didn't seem to be very popular so I'm rewording it so be more specific.  My spouse did make that mistake with 3 MWBCs and the breaker did indeed trip, though I think that it damaged the breaker(s) because even after they tripped, one wire still had electricity.  I capped all three wires (individually) and wrapped then ends in electric tape while waiting for an electrician to come have a look.
